# How do I make a password for my html website in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get this code to redirect to another page when the person types in hello. What should I do?

```
<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your password");

   if (person == hello) {
        window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
    }
    else {
        confirm("Invalid Password")}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question and title are totally unrelated.

Comment: It's generally a very bad idea to use javascript (or ANY client-side scripting) to control password access.   The only way you could be less secure is printing passwords directly on the page for all users to see.

Comment: This is just an experiment password project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the others have mentioned, this is really insecure.  But for the sake of this project, try this:

```
<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var person = prompt("Please enter your password");

   if (person == 'hello') {
        document.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
   }
   else {
        confirm("Invalid Password")
   }
}
</script>
```

1. Make sure to add quotes around hello, since it's a string you want to compare   to the person variable.
2. Instead of using `window.open()`, just change the `document.location.href` property to the new URL.  That will load the new URL into the current window.  Window.open() opens a new browser window like the name implies, but that does not always work due to popup blockers.

Answer (score -1):

just try this

```
<button onClick="window.location='page_name.php';" value="click here" />
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question?